# How to use PHP Switch with long range of numbers

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a randomizer in PHP with ranges from 1 to 100.

```
$var = rand (1,100);
```

I had a hard time switching all 100 of them as so.

```
switch($var) {
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
case 9:
case 10:
case 11:
case 12:
case 13:
case 14:
case 15:
case 16:
case 17:
case 18:
case 19:
case 20:
case 21:
case 22:
case 23:
case 24:
case 25:
case 26:
case 27:
case 28:
case 29:
case 30:
case 31:
case 32:
case 33:
case 34:
case 35:
case 36:
case 37:
case 38:
case 39:
case 40:
case 41:
case 42:
case 43:
case 44:
case 45:
case 46:
case 47:
case 48:
case 49:
case 50:
case 51:
case 52:
case 53:
case 54:
case 55:
case 56:
case 57:
case 58:
case 59:
case 60:
case 61:
case 62:
case 63:
case 64:
case 65:
case 66:
case 67:
case 68:
case 69:
case 70:
case 71:
case 72:
case 73:
case 74:
case 75:
case 76:
case 77:
case 78:
case 79:
case 80:
case 81:
case 82:
case 83:
case 84:
case 85:
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;font-family: \'Oswald\', sans-serif;">You unboxed a common!</p>';
    echo '<img src="common.jpg" width=300 height=300 style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"/>';
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;font-family: \'Titillium Web\', sans-serif;">Your random number was  '.'<span style="color:red">'.$var.'<span>'.'</p>';
    break;
case 86:
case 87:
case 88:
case 89:
case 90:
case 91:
case 92:
case 93:
case 94:
case 95:
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;font-family: \'Oswald\', sans-serif;">You unboxed a Rare!</p>';
    echo '<img src="rare.jpg" width=300 height=300 style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"/>';
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;font-family: \'Titillium Web\', sans-serif;">Your random number was  '.'<span style="color:red">'.$var.'<span>'.'</p>';
    break;
case 96:
case 97:
case 98:
case 99:
case 100:
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;font-family: \'Oswald\', sans-serif;">You unboxed a Extraordinary!</p>';
    echo '<img src="extra.jpg" width=300 height=300 style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"/>';
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;font-family: \'Titillium Web\', sans-serif;">Your random number was '.'<span style="color:red">'.$var.'<span>'.'</p>';
```

};

Thing is, I want to make it with a range from 1 to 1000. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to use switch with range instead of doing like I did.

Is there something like:

```
case ($var > 50):
    echo "Something like this";
    break;
```

I'm pretty sure this doesn't work but there should be a different way right?

Comment: unfortunately there IS... your logic much more sounds like an if/elseif construction rather than switch/case

Answer (score 1):

It may be more convenient to put these into an array and reference them by index as such:

```
$var = rand (1,100);
$arr = array(1 => "some html here", ...);

echo $arr[$var];
```

In addition to being able to maximize the readability of your code, expansion is made simpler, and you open the door to multiple data sources to populate your array.

Comment: The OP's problem seems to be something like a probability arithmetic. If the chance hits above 50, then something is displayed, if it's between 50 and 70 somethig else is displayed and if it's 70 - 100 - third thing is displayed. The solution with the array seems for be much worse than the multiple empty cases

Comment: Using range() may help in that case.  I may be making it worse by saying that.

Answer (score 1):

Ranges are unfortunately NOT supported like this for switch/case constructs. Whatever you put after `case` must evaluate to the same value as the expression in your `switch` does.

For your use case it is simple enough to just use an if/else statement, as such:

```
if (x <= 85) {
   // do something
} else if (x <= 95) {
   // do something else
} else if ...
```

Edit: It does seem like the value does not necessarily have to match in the sense that I claimed above (looks like it is enough that the expression evaluates to true OR matches the provided value..?). However, my answer still stands as the answer that curtis1000 posted is a highly unintuitive use of switch/case; this is definitely a job for if/else.